# Connect display over network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vnc

I have 2 imac's i want to use a external displays with a ubuntu system.  I've looked into vnc, but the lag is too much for use with video or visuals.  any suggestions on an alternative software?

Answer (score 0):

Any network-based display system will include high amounts of lag. This is the nature of the differences between connections used internally to a computer and between it's various components and the connections used in networking: They are simply not the same thing, nor are they even comparable.

Are you wanting to use this like a KVM system, or a remote control, or as screens in addition to the one(s) already connected to the ubuntu box?

Comment: as a screen in addition to the one connected

Comment: i was looking at x11 but i cant find a way to use the program on more than one display.